# Probability mass function for exchangeable random vector

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

I have a strange point of confusion I'd like some help clearing up.

Let $\mathbf{X}=(X_{1},X_{2},\ldots,X_{n})$ be an exchangeable random vector taking values in $\mathbb{Z}^{n}$, where by exchangeable I mean, for any permutation $\sigma$ of $\{1,\ldots ,n\}$
$$
\mathbb{P}[(X_{1},X_{2},\ldots,X_{n})=\mathbf{x}]=\mathbb{P}[(X_{\sigma(1)},X_{\sigma(2)},\ldots,X_{\sigma(n)})=\mathbf{x}]
$$
for an $n$ dimensional vector $\mathbf{x}$. Fix $\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{Z}^{n}$. I'm interested in 
$$
\mathbb{P}[(X_{\sigma(1)},X_{\sigma(2)},\ldots,X_{\sigma(n)})=\mathbf{x} \text{ for some}\, \sigma].
$$
Now let us further specify that all $X_{i}$ are $iid$ and have full support on $\mathbb{Z}$. Then 
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}[(X_{\sigma(1)},X_{\sigma(2)},\ldots,X_{\sigma(n)})=\mathbf{x} \text{ for some}\, \sigma]=n!\mathbb{P}[(X_{1},X_{2},\ldots,X_{n})=\mathbf{x}]
\\
=n!\prod_{i=1}^{n}\mathbb{P}(X_{i}=x_{i})\geq n!\left(\min_{i\in\{1,...,n\}}\mathbb{P}(X_{i}=x_{i})\right)^{n}\rightarrow \infty\quad \text{as } n\rightarrow\infty.
\end{align}
This obviously can't be correct but I don't know where my mistake is?

Comment: The factor $n!$ appears only if all the coordinates of $\mathbf x$ are different. For this case $\min\limits_{i\in\{1,...,n\}}\mathbb{P}(X_{i}=x_{i})$ depends on $n$ and should decrease in $n$. Therefore you cannot conclude that this minimum in the power $n$ decreases slower than $n!$

Comment: Good catch. Thanks.